# Animate text in final cut pro: knocking previous text further from centre

Tags: macos, video, imovie, video-editing, final-cut-pro

How can I animate a sentence in final cut pro,

where each word in the sentence slides in from the right (violently), slamming into place in the middle of the screen, knocking the previous word further to the left (but not off the screen, it just stops when the new word stops.)

I hope that can help you understand what I'm going for, I can't find any examples of this effect even though I'm certain I've seen it before and often.

Comment: I think Motion might be the app to try for that - though I'm a complete newb on video, so someone else would have to deal with the specifics. Maybe https://video.stackexchange.com would be a better fit?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm surprised Apple would force you to pay for a second app to complete a task like this. Thanks for the video.stackexchange.com suggestion, maybe this should be migrated?

Comment: We're in 'Pro App' territory - which means you pay for everything. Consumers won't pay much for stuff, pros will. ...& sure, flag to see if a mod can migrate it.

Comment: My guess is this would be closed as not “production grade” question - someone producing movies professionally would have in-depth experience in several tools to make animated text. This is very much on topic here so lets not migrate unless someone from a chat room / moderator of that site says they want this exact question.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple tool for that job is [Motion](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/motion/id434290957?mt=12) and it can make plug in for iMovie or just do the work you want. Adobe Premiere Pro probably does what you want, but instead of a one time $50 charge - that is $20 a month subscription. You do get a free trial of Premiere so you could make sure it would work for your project.

You could possibly find someone who already knows motion to make you a plug in or find one that works for your needs, but the general solution to making custom text animations is to use Motion or the Adobe CC suite tools for video

- https://filmora.wondershare.com/imovie/top-5-imovie-plugins.html